# How to restore WorkItems' old component after changing them to new component

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I mistakenly changed the components of different areas to a single component. I created a query for components without realizing that there was a mistake in the query and changed the components of all the areas to a single component. Because of this 13K worktimes got updated.

It is not possible to change each item manually. Is there any way to restore the old components of those work items?

I explored the APIs which return the list of all the work items in the query. Also, I explored the API which retrieves the information for old and new component values.
I am not sure how can I change back to the values of the old components for all 13K work items.

Get work item history API:
[https://dev.azure.com/astera/Centerprise/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=5.1](https://dev.azure.com/astera/Centerprise/_apis/wit/workItems/%7Bid%7D/updates?api-version=5.1)

Get work item ids from query:
[https://dev.azure.com/astera/Centerprise/_apis/wit/wiql/{queryid}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/astera/Centerprise/_apis/wit/wiql/%7Bqueryid%7D?api-version=6.0)

Comment: Refer the Examples section here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP for updating your workitems, There's no direct API, I think you need to update it manually by looking into your WorkItem history

Comment: Could you please clarify what's `components of different areas`? Are they different fields value? It's recommended to share a screenshot to show what's updated.

Comment: Hi @AbdurRehman, may i know if there's any update? Clarify what's updated could help for troubelshooting, and benifit for script checking to restore the component back.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct Rest API for this operation, You need to Get History of your API and then use this [Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to update the component by the values returned from your Get History API Refer the Examples section from the same document to update specific parameters:-

**Update Work Item API PS code:-**

```
$PAT = "s3xw5xxxxxx"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"  # Update organization name
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"  # Update project name
$ApiVersion = "7.1-preview.3"
$WorkItemId = "6"

# Construct the URL for the PATCH request
$WorkItemId = "6"  # Replace {id} with the actual ID of the work item
$PatchUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/$ProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/6?api-version=7.1-preview.3"

# JSON payload for the PATCH request
$PatchBody = @'
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.History",
    "value": "Linking to a blog article for context"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "Hyperlink",
      "url": "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx"
    }
  }
]
'@

# Invoke the PATCH request
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PatchUrl -Method Patch -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT"))
    "Content-Type" = "application/json-patch+json"
} -Body $PatchBody
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]